# HtmlAgilityPack file loading

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a problem, when I trying to load file from filesystem. Issue that in value of some HTML control I have less than sign "<" inside span value

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionReadEncoding = true;

//StreamReader str = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"E:\HTMLS\OEL\1030,1.html",Encoding.UTF8,true);

doc.Load(str.BaseStream, Encoding.ASCII);
//string streamString = str.ReadToEnd().
str.Close();
//all nodes

doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "#text" && (x.InnerText == "\r\n\t" || x.InnerText == "\r\n" || x.InnerText == "\r\n\t\t")).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
List<HtmlNode> listHtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").ToList();
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: You don't describe what the problem is - do you mean that you see an exception? If so, you should describe that in detail so that people know what the issue is. Either way, you suggest that the body text inside your `span` has a `<` character in it. If that's the case, your document is not valid HTML and would not/should not parse correctly - the character should be written as the HTML entity `&lt;` instead.

Comment: problem is when parse html tag like this <span>aaaa<bbbb</span> . when I'm trying to get span inner text, I'm getting only aaaa not aaaa<bbbb

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have symbols such as `<` as content in your HTML. Having them in your html makes the html invalid and will cause the HTMLAgility pack to not perform correctly.

If you need them in your html you need to encode them. `<` becomes `%lt;` see here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: But should I encode only content of tag ? can you show me example what should I do when I get Stream from HttpWebResponse how to save in file system

Comment: You should only encode the characters that are classed as content of the html (the text between tags) and not the ones that are actual html code.

Comment: There is no code to give. Just open up your HTML file and replace all the invalid symbols with their encoded version.